# Laravel : Overriding route for specific route in voyager

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I am trying to override a route for creating a row. (posting, not viewing)

http://lsapp.dev/admin/cpu-speed/create

In web.php

I modified

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
    Route::post('/cpu-speed',['uses' => 'Admin\Mobiles\CPUSpeedController@store',  'as' => 'store']);

});
```

Also I created Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Mobiles;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class CPUSpeedController extends Controller
{
    public function store(){
        return 'hello';
    }

    public function create(){
        return 'create';
    }
}
```

But it throws the following error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Route [voyager.cpu-speed.store] not defined.
>   (View:
>   /var/www/html/lsapp/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/bread/edit-add.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are only naming it `store` here:

```
Route::post('/cpu-speed',['uses' => 'Admin\Mobiles\CPUSpeedController@store',  'as' => 'store']);
```

It should probably be:

```
Route::post('/cpu-speed',['uses' => 'Admin\Mobiles\CPUSpeedController@store',  'as' => 'voyager.cpu-speed.store']);
```

I'm not entirely sure this will work, since it may be interpreted and descend into the Voyager package, rather than just reading your `web.php` file, but I believe it will do what you like.

Comment: Glad to hear it.